# Difference in Indexed and Reviewed items in Mathscinet

Tags: mathematics

What is the difference between the two item types: Indexed and Reviewed in MathSciNet? I have seen some research articles in the same issue of an indexed mathematics journal being categorized differently. Some are indexed while others are reviewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexed items have only their basic metadata copied to MathSciNet. Hundreds of journals and book series are routinely indexed by MathSciNet, presumably by a partially-automated process that requires relatively little hands-on work for each item. Indexing is handled by full-time staff.

Reviewed items, on the other hand, have summaries written manually by experts in the field. In order for a paper to be reviewed, it must first be indexed, and an expert must read it and agree to write a review for MathSciNet. As a result, many indexed items may never be reviewed.

Comment: I have heard from some senior Professors that Reviewed items are more trustworthy than indexed ones. So, is that the case or it's just that MathSciNet failed to get the item reviewed as many experts in the field rejected it for reviewing?

Comment: @Hardeep Have you thought how much *work* it would be to review all papers?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Yes, I agree that it would be lots of work. I am really thankful to MathSciNet for making our lives easy. But, I wanted to ask how the process is done and if indexed items are not of the quality that's why those were not reviewed or the reason is something else.

Comment: @Hardeep I don't think you will be able to make a determination that could be applied to individual papers. It may be true *statistically* that papers nobody cares about aren't reviewed, but I bet that lots of papers people *do* care about are also not reviewed and that, as a consequence, when you see a non-reviewed paper, you won't be able to tell whether it's good or not just from that fact.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth my first research paper is shown as pending and might be indexed or reviewed soon I found out that my colleague's recent paper got indexed and so I asked the guide and he said that probably the paper might not be of high quality. I was a little bit anxious hearing that. Thank you for clearing up the confusion though.